# Converting inc files to php files

Tags: php, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, include

I am working on a project that is in asp. My client wants me to convert ASP to ASP.NET. 
The project has got many .inc files which is placed inside an include folder and these inc files are called

```
<!-- #include file="../includes/example.inc" -->
```

in many pages. Most of these inc files have either variables or constants declared that are used in many pages or functions(written in VBScript).  Now my client had asked me to try converting these inc files to php files(Don't have any clue about php as I have never worked on it before).

My question here is

1. How effective would it be converting these inc files to php.?
2. How can I call the functions in the php page from aspx page?
3. If not converting to php what would be the better method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you asked to convert INC to PHP because INC to ASP.NET wasn't going well?

Comment: @DaveMroz Actually I was thinking of converting the inc files to class. But again the client doesnt want to rewrite the whole codes. He just wants to convert the asp pages to aspx and make it run.So he asked us to convert the inc files to php

Comment: If your client wants a site in asp.net then forget about php, especially if you have no experience there

Comment: Don't do it.  I'll write a full answer as to why, but after reading this, just don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This will require the re-writing of all of these flies as PHP has no VBScript support. Therefore, the 'effectiveness' is at best an objective statement being that it is contingent on the competency and skill sets of the individual performing the migration.
2. You cannot call functions in a php page from an aspx page (inheritly). You can (attempt) to do this, but I would highly recommend not doing this.
3. My only recommendation would be to start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Abort!

Don't go gown this rabbit hole!  I agree with everything that @ohgodwhy said, and I'll add some details.

First, a little background.  ASP files [usually] have a .ASP file extension and are always written in VbScript.  PHP files have a .PHP extension and are always written in PHP. .NET files have a .ASPX extension are usually written in C# or VB.NET.  Notice that there are no overlaps between technologies or file extensions. I'll talk about INC files in a second.

When IIS interprets the code, it picks the correct processor based on the file extension and then interprets the code/script, does whatever it's programmed to do, and generates an HTML output for the browser to render.  In this case, the first pass of the ASP processor is to gather up all of the include files and process them *in the same language as the parent file*. I'm going to assume that your INC files are actually ASP files (regardless of their file extension), so they get included and then processed as ASP files.  If they contain PHP code, you're going to get an error right off the bat.

If you try to combine technologies in one project, the server has to use multiple interpreters/engines to get this all to process and get to that final HTML.  IF (and this is a big IF), but IF you can get them all to work together, you still have the problem of passing data back and forth between the technologies because they're being run in different parts of the server.  You can't have the ASP processor include a PHP file and have it magically work.

It is possible to have PHP, ASP, and/or .NET coexist in the same project, but not the way you want it to.  I've done it a few times and the project (and server) have to be configured very carefully and then passing the data back and forth becomes the challenge because each of the technologies is working in its own memory space and is not accessible to the other.  Again, it CAN be done, but it's going to be a MAJOR challenge and it's going to involve some creative programming - probably far more than what your client wants to do.

Bottom line: go tell the client that converting to PHP is a waste of time and money.  You have ASP files and INC (which are really ASP) files.  Why involve another technology?  Your options are to rewrite the whole thing in ASP, rewrite the whole thing in PHP, or rewrite the whole thing in .NET, but don't mix and match.

(A note for some ubertechnical downvoters: I simplified this a tad to make it clearer for this example!)